# getting Developer Notifications about OGNL exceptions after upgrading to struts 2.3.14.2 from 2.3.1.2

Tags: struts

I have my web application built using struts 2.3.1.2. I have following pages/actions where I don't get any OGNL exception as a warning/notification.

1. JSP page - containing 3 text fields name, address, phone
2. struts.xml file - devMode = true and corresponding action entry using default interceptor stack
3. action class where I have properties only for two request parameters i.e. for name and address

Above is running fine and I don't get any warning/notification exception.

Now, recently I have upgraded to struts 2.3.14.2 And I have started to get below warning/notification exception on log file:

```
Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message): 

Unexpected Exception caught setting 'start' on 'class com.xyz.DetailsActionSupport: 
Error setting expression 'start' with value ['0', ] - Error setting expression 'start' with value ['0', ] - [unknown location]        at  
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.handleRuntimeException(OgnlValueStack.java:201)  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:178) at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:152) at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:329)   at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:241)     at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) and more ...
```

By google search, found two answers:

1. to add the exclude parameters in struts.xml for Param interceptor
2. disable the development mode defined in struts.xml

I can do that, but, don't understand ***what has changed in struts version so it has started to print the exceptions as notifications/warnings?***

Below link will tells us how it shows warning exception:
http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/parameters-interceptor.html
Refer the section ***Warning on missing parameters*** from above link

Comment: get the following warning exception: SEVERE: Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message):
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'search' on 'class demo.ItemSearchAction: Error setting expression 'search' with value ['search', ]
Error setting expression 'search' with value ['search', ] - [unknown location]
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.handleRuntimeException(OgnlValueStack.java:201)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:178)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:152