# logMissingProperties in struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

When the jsp send an response to and action, the OGNL tries to match the request parameters with action properties. And if it could not find any property it will raise and excption trace in the stack as below:

```
Error setting expression 'destinationUnknownAccount' with value ['', ] - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.handleRuntimeException(OgnlValueStack.java:197)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:174)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:318)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:231)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.google.code.rees.scope.struts2.ConversationInterceptor.intercept(ConversationInterceptor.java:159)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.google.code.rees.scope.struts2.SessionInterceptor.intercept(SessionInterceptor.java:82)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at net.iranet.isc.saba.web.interceptors.CharEncodingInterceptor.intercept(CharEncodingInterceptor.java:82)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at net.iranet.isc.saba.web.interceptors.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:63)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at net.iranet.isc.saba.web.interceptors.SessionInterceptor.intercept(SessionInterceptor.java:58)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: No object in the CompoundRoot has a publicly accessible property named 'destinationUnknownAccount' (no setter could be found). - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.CompoundRootAccessor.setProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:106)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2332)
    at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
    at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:183)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:170)
    ... 39 more
```

You know this trace will not help at all, even in development. A simple message seems to be enough!

I know I could disable this by changing some log levels.

I found the same question at [getting Developer Notifications about OGNL exceptions after upgrading to struts 2.3.14.2 from 2.3.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106645/getting-developer-notifications-about-ognl-exceptions-after-upgrading-to-struts) which seems not been answered!

Recently I found  something which SOUNDS I can disable this behavior by below constant

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.logMissingProperties" value="false" />
```

Which did not worked! 
Any comments

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the struts2 `devMode` and OGNL exceptions/warnings, will be supressed.

Define the below in your struts.xml file

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
```

Comment: The devMode feature is very use full, during the devMode this stack trace is useless!

Comment: `I know I could disable this by changing some log levels.` - this is only that can be done.